# How to secure method of Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

Since many website will calling service by Web API. In that case, those methods will be exposed for every one. How can I ensure only my web site can calling my Web API service?

Comment: put files above document root

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please list the methods you have tried and if possible with source code. It is expected that you will have undertaken some effort before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to secure it as a developer is to get the IT people to do it by limiting access down by IP address from site to site. You could also do this in the app by validating the incoming IP addreseses. Sometimes IP addresses change sometimes they don't. Whenever I have done this have used certificates as there is a trust on both sides of the data divide. Have a look at John Petersens article [Making web api's secure](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) it has a section on implementing IP security in your app as well as x509 certificates; complete with code examples that I wont reproduce here. You could try and secure it with SSL and create your own key / trust but its easier to maintain (imo) using x509. Perversely it was much easier in the web service world Microsoft had an API  to do this much more simple in WSE extension..